# Given a dictionary and a key, "get_nth_element_of_value" returns the nth element of a list located at the given key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on some practice problems, and I do not know how to write code foe the following condiction:

If n is out of range, it should return None.

```
def get_nth_element_of_value(obj, key, n):
    for key, value in obj.items():
        if not isinstance(obj.get(key), list):
            return None
        if isinstance(value, list) and value == []:
            return None
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value[n]
        if isinstance(value, list) and value[n] > range(list):
            return None

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know my code is not as lean as it could be, but I am new to python and coding so I am still learning the basics.

Comment: Have you tried changing the last check ```value[n] > range(list)``` into something like ```n > len(value)```?

Comment: I tried, and I still get the same error. I need something in the code saying if the location at index [n] is outside the range, then return "None"

Comment: I'd investigate using a try/except block to catch the `IndexError` and return `None` instead. I'd imagine that this is what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need

```
def get_nth_element_of_value(obj, key, n):
    value = obj.get(key)
    if value and len(value) >= n:    #Check if key in DICT and len of value is > = n
        return value[n] 
    return None
```